# Copying local git config into docker container

Tags: linux, git, docker, docker-compose

I'm using both docker and docker-compose to host what for the most part is a LAMP stack. I'd like to be able to use git inside one of my containers without it asking for my user.email and user.name on push after I build. Along with other things such as my push.default and branch settings. Is there any good way to have docker or docker-compose copy the results of `git config --list` to a file in the container, which I can then use with my entrypoint to setup the git config.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Is there any good way to have docker or docker-compose copy the results of git config --list to a file in the container, which I can then use with my entrypoint to setup the git config.

You really needn't do that to reach your aims, there is a outbox solution:

For your host machine which run git, all the contents of `git config --list` is stored in files:

- If use `git config --system` to configure them, they are stored in `/etc/gitconfig`
- If use `git config --global` to configure them, they are stored in `~/.gitconfig`

So, you just need to mount the files to containers, then can reuse the git configure on host machine.

Something like follows, FYI.

- If host use `--global` to configure git:

  ```
  docker run --rm -it -v ~/.gitconfig:/etc/gitconfig your_image_with_git git config --list
  ```

  output: `user.name=xxx`
- If host use `--system` to configure git:

  ```
  docker run --rm -it -v /etc/gitconfig:/etc/gitconfig your_image_with_git git config --list
  ```

  output: `user.name=yyy`

For `docker-compose`, you can just configure `volumes` to define the mount.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, this is great. I'll use docker-compose to set up a volume from ~/.gitconfig to dockers ~/.gitconfig unless you think there's a reason to not do that.

Comment: I'm not sure if the second `~/.gitconfig` will be explained in container, maybe in host machine. Maybe had to use absolute path for container part, something like `~/.gitconfig:/root/.gitconfig`, not `~/.gitconfig:~/.gitconfig`, anyway, you could have a try, I'm not quite sure for compose behavior about this.

Comment: I have a user setup to use when attached to the container anyway, so they have a home directory from /username/home I can use. Thanks

Comment: In the end @lagom I went with `- type: bind
          source: $HOME/.gitconfig
          target: /home/developer/.gitconfig` in my docker-compose.yml and it works a treat

Comment: I found that mounting my gitconfig as a volume in docker-compose didn't work for me as I had individual build instructions for my containers. This triggered the build instructions in the Dockerfile which is where the call to git happened (via a dependency in yarn.lock). I found that setting the gitconfig in the Dockerfile before the yarn instruction `RUN git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:`
`RUN git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`  did the trick - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545852/fetching-git-behind-proxy-in-docker-container

Comment: @whatapalaver, of course, that question you mentioned is totally different with this one. For this one, the OP said: `entrypoint to setup the git config`, this means it intends to use git in running container, volume works there. While in the question you mentioned, it use git in `RUN git clone https://github.com/sofetch/slack-standup-bot.git`, `RUN` happened in build time, volume defintely not work.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't meaning to suggest your answer wasn't correct. Just signposting for others like myself, who came to the question and answer for slightly different situations. Your answer helped me get to a final solution.

Comment: Can someone add a sample `docker-compose` to the answer. :) would be of much help.

Comment: `volumes:
      - "~/.gitconfig:/etc/gitconfig"`

Comment: This broke my VS Code docker plugin git functionality. The git plugin was complaining that .gitconfig was busy and couldn't be written to.

Answer (score 1):

For the `docker-compose`, this worked well for me (based on @atline's answer)

```
    volumes:
  - "~/.gitconfig:/etc/gitconfig"
```

Answer (score -5):

I am assuming you want to be able to use git inside a container but at the same time you do not want to type your username and password again and again?

The method that I am able to come up with is simple add the `git config` command in the Dockerfile.

The reason is you will be supplying the password in plain-text anyways one way or the other.

So, my suggestion is adding these lines to the Dockerfile.

```
RUN git config --global user.name "your username"
RUN git config --global user.password "your password"
```

Comment: Forgot to reply, this wouldn't work as a solution for me for multiple reasons: * I'm not the only user. * this restricts production usage. * I'm definitely not going to commit my git password to anywhere, and personally I wouldn't ever store it in my git config either. * bad practice, hard coding details rather than taking from where they're kept updated.

Comment: Dockerfiles can read environment variables, which would let this be an option without committing the actual values to your codebase.

Comment: You may as well just use `COPY` though, bind volumes are the real solution as atline mentions in his answer