# Configure git while building docker image

Tags: git, docker

**THE PROBLEM**

I have a git configuration that uses both **access token** and **client certificates**. While building docker image I need to use the same git configuration (in order to reach all required sources).

---

**WHAT I DID** for now is something like this in `Dockerfile` and it works for me:

```
(...)
ARG SRC="/src"
RUN mkdir ${SRC}

# copying cert files inside docker image
COPY certificate.crt ${SRC}
COPY certificate.key ${SRC}

# configuring the same git settings inside
RUN git config --global user.name "${USER_NAME}"
RUN git config --global user.email "${EMAIL}"
RUN git config --global url."https://${ACCESS_TOKEN}@git_domain.com/".insteadOf "ssh://git@git_domain.com/"
RUN git config --global http."https://git_domain.com/".sslCert "/src/certificate.crt"
RUN git config --global http."https://git_domain.com/".sslKey "/src/certificate.key"
(...)
```

---

**THE QUESTIONS ARE**

Maybe is there some more "laconic" or simple way?

Is it possible to use existing local file `.gitconfig`? Somehow to specify path to it?

I found this question [Copying local git config into docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52819584/copying-local-git-config-into-docker-container/52827029), but `docker run` doesn't fit. I need to do the similar thing, but using `docker build`.

Comment: Git configuration is stored in pretty simple (ini-like) files that can easily be produced manually. For example global configuration is stored in `~/.gitconfig` (see [this section for details](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES)).

Comment: Also remember that you can very easily read the `docker history` of an image, or copy the `.gitconfig` file out, and get these credentials back.  Similarly with the certificate files.  I'd recommend pulling the application source before you run `docker build`, and injecting TLS keys at run time.

Comment: @JoachimSauer okay, I know, but what should I do next? How to pass git configuration from `~/.gitconfig` right inside docker image?

Answer (score 3):

> I need to do the similar thing, but using docker build.

I would generate the right gitconfig file locally first, then, once generated, COPY it from the Dockerfile, during a `docker build`.

```
COPY .gitconfig .
```